# Jenkins pipeline warnings plugin and the ability to suppress trend graphs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Within a jenkins pipeline does anyone know if it is possible to suppress trend graphs from appearing after warnings analysis?

My pipeline is currently outputting pylint and jslint output as follows:

```
step([
        $class: 'WarningsPublisher',
        parserConfigurations: [[
            parserName: 'PyLint',
            pattern: '**/artifacts/pylint.out, **/artifacts/pylint_test.out'
        ], [
            parserName: 'JSLint',
            pattern: '**/artifacts/jslint.xml'
        ]
    ]])
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-plugin